# What is the issue with installation of ArcGIS?

Tags: installation, gis

I extract ArcGIS and then install that, but in the last step, it is written click finish to exit this installation. When I click on "Finish", mouse will change to circle shape and no will happen and it remains in this situation without finalizing. 
Has anyone experienced this problem previously and knows how to resolve it?

I should add that I had a old version GIS that I uproot that and then install the new one. I have a advanced license. My windows is 10.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FxuTi.png)

Comment: You might have better luck on their support site- this is a site about programming.

Comment: I asked this question on gis.stachexchange, but they said I should ask my question here.

Comment: Those folks on gis.SE.com are writing nonsense then, because your question isn't a programming question. In any case, the support site *of ArcGIS* should be of help.